# Como utilizar a imagem gerada no html em outra página

Tags: php

Estou convertendo uma string para imagem para ser utilizada em um boleto bancário. Tendo em vista esta necessidade, tenho como exemplo a seguinte varável:

```
$string = 10499.10657 01500.110045 00002.710038 9 79320000000000
```

Obs.: estes da variável estão em string UTF-8

**Código:**

```
$font  = 5;
$width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
$height = imagefontheight($font);

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 65, 65, 65);
imagestring($image, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```

E me retorna uma imagem na aba com o valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em outro arquivo, tenho um template html que necessito inserir, mas como faço para realizar esta passagem via variável na tag `<img src="<?php ?>">`  para apenas mostrar onde eu quero, não executando nesta aba como está ocorrendo?

Li em alguns tópicos em inglês que se faz necessário converter para a base64 segundo meu entendimento, de fato se faz necessário?
Referência: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299230/convert-string-to-image-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode fazer o seguinte

```
<img src='arquivo_de_boleto.php'>
```

ou ainda pode transformar sua imagem em um `base64`

```
$font  = 5;
$width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
$height = imagefontheight($font);

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 65, 65, 65);
imagestring($image, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor); 
ob_start();  
imagepng($image);
$imagedata = ob_get_clean();
```

e na pagina mais em baixo em php vc printaria assim

```
<?php echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imagedata).'">';
```

--- Para modificar a fonte ----

seria algo assim

```
$font = imageloadfont('./fonte.ttf');
imagestring($image, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor);
```

da uma lida na doc. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagestring.php

Comment: Funcionou certinho, obrigado.